# If "votable" means capable of being voted upon, then what word means capable of being used to vote?

Tags: single-word-requests

If a legal matter is *votable*, it is capable of being voted upon. What, then, is a voucher, or a stock certificate, that is capable of being used to vote?

Is that thing still *votable*; i.e., is this another sense of that same word?

Comment: Yes, but it's not the certificate that's called *votable,* it's the shares that the certificate represent thart are *votable*.  The certificate simply proves you own the *votable* shares.  For example here's some lines from an SEC filing that talks about *votable* shares: [*Also includes 2,930 restricted shares which are votable by the individual*](http://ir.quidel.com/mobile.view?c=94060&v=202&=3&id=aHR0cDovL2FwaS50ZW5rd2l6YXJkLmNvbS9maWxpbmcueG1sP2lwYWdlPTM0MDUwNjUmRFNFUT0xJlNFUT0yMCZTUURFU0M9U0VDVElPTl9QQUdFJmV4cD0mc3Vic2lkPTU3])

Comment: @Jim I believe the term is *voting shares*, at least that is the case in Britain. You are talking here about what UK Company Law describes as *Ordinary Shares*, and in the United States is known as *Common Stock*. One of the key features of both Ordinary Shares and Common Stock is that they carry the right to vote. So a good generic term that might be applied generally across different jurisdictions is *voting shares*. In many years in the accountancy profession I do not recall any use of the term *votable shares*. Indeed my spell-checker underlines it in red.

Comment: @WS2- I have also heard the term *voting shares*.  Nevertheless, [here's another filing that uses "votable"](https://www.geam.com/ExternalWar/static/en_US/pdfs/additional_info/uk-stewardship-04-06-2015-12-32-03-822.pdf): *Shares Voted: 
6,550,463  
Votable Shares: 
6,550,463*

Comment: @WS2- *accountancy* Eh?  Have you ever wanted to be a lion tamer?

Comment: @Jim I looked at that but I think it is wrong. It doesn't matter because everyone understands what it means. It is interesting that Wikipedia redirects *Votable shares* to *Voting interests*.

Comment: @Jim re *lion tamer* - the short answer is *no*. The longer answer is on my profile. After 40 years of numbers, I did decide I had to do something else - but not lion taming!

Comment: 'votive' can be used to vote

Comment: I have numerous times read the term "votable shares" in proxy statements and the like, in the US.  (It's not unusual for a term such as "votable" to have multiple meanings that collide in some circumstances.)

Comment: Shares confer ***voting rights*** on shareholders. The shares  you own are either shares with voting rights or without them. Votable shares may appear in some magazine like Forbes but it ain't a kosher business term. That said, voting shares is OK because not all shares are voting shares.

Answer (score 1):

*ballot* [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ballot):

> The piece of paper used to record someone’s vote.

Edit:

In response to OP's comment, I would use the adjectives *unmarked* or *blank* to indicate that a ballot, for example, is able to be used to vote.

Edit:

In response to Jim's comment, I would recommended *identification*, or, *identifying*.

Comment: That's the noun, what is the adjective that makes it such a noun? A stock certificate, for example, can both grant or deny voting rights so a stock certificate that does grant voting rights is "what"? Votable?

Comment: @Kyle- Unfortunately that's not what the OP's after.  Yes, you can literally vote *on* the ballot, but OP is asking for the term for something (like a stock certificate) that proves you have the right to vote.  In other words, you *use* it when you vote to prove you are allowed to do so.

Comment: Classes of equity which confer the right to vote on the holder are called *voting* stock.

Answer (score 1):

A share of some company that one owns may be defined as [*voting*](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/v/votingshares.asp) or *non-voting* under the terms of its issuance.  "Preferred" shares, which typically get paid a fixed dividend before regular shares, are commonly non-voting.